# #NAME? How to read a formula bar to change the formula of an error - NOT overwritting it

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, string-formatting, formula

I've been stuck on this problem for a very long time. I've come up with ways around it but each one is bringing more problems to the table.

My macro copys and pastes info from Microsoft Word into Excel and then formats the excel sheet.

Some of the cells however show a #NAME? error.  The reason for this is that the cell copies in " =------- List SC".  I need to get into this cell and remove the "=------" and leave only the string List SC.

I cannot just over ride it however because each time it changes. It might be "List FL" or "List BP" or any other variation.

I cannot do an InStr or any other function because the VBA code only reads it as an error and doesn't read the formula bar. It only reads "#NAME?" or recognizes an error.

Does anyone have suggestions as to what I can do?

I have included a picture of the issue.  The highlights are the error and formula bar.

Thank you!

Jonathan

[image: snippet of the formula bar and error]

Comment: Can't you do the InStr seach for `=-----` while you're copying from Word to Excel?

Comment: Hi Jack, when you say "while" do you mean before I copy? As it's copying I don't think I can do any manipulations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that I can store the formula into a string and  add an " ' " as the first character in the string. I can then replace the existing formula in the cell with the string (below called stfF).

This is my code.

Dim strF As String

```
For x = 4 To 100  
   strF = "'" & Cells(x, 1).Formula
   Cells(x, 1) = strF 
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

> My macro copys and pastes info from Microsoft Word into Excel...Some of the cells however show a #NAME? error.

You must edit the string you get from Word *before* you paste it into Excel. You must remove all invalid characters from the string. Then you can paste it as a formula.

If `----List` is the value you want in the cell, then precede it with a single quote: `'----List` so it will be interpreted as text.

Comment: I found an easier way using Ky11 suggestion. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 2):

In VBA, use the `.Formula` method to access the actual formula used and do the string replace on it.

```
With Cells(1,3)
    .Formula = Replace(.Formula, "=------ ", "")
End With
```

Comment: Hi yk11, this doesn't seem to be working.  When I get to the cell it doesn't recognize what is in the formula bar. With my cursor over the cell it simply reads "Error 2029". As a result I don't think a Replace can work.

Comment: Turn on "Show Formulas" to see what Excel actually has in there.

Comment: Hi Yk11, this will actually work as all I need to do is have the user view the formula.  Do you know how I can turn on show formulas in vba for only column A?

Comment: Boom! I got it :-) This was a great path to go down thanks yk11